# Compiling Fortran external symbols

Tags: compilation, fortran, symbols

When compiling fortran code into object files: how does the compiler determine the symbol names?

when I use the intrinsic function "getarg" the compiler converts it into a symbol called "_getarg@12"

I looked in the external libraries and found that the symbol name inside is called "_getarg@16" what is the significance of the "@[number]" at the end of "getarg" ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`_name@length` is highly Windows-specific name mangling applied to the name of routines that obey the `stdcall` (or `__stdcall` by the name of the keyword used in C) calling convention, a variant of the Pascal calling convention. This is the calling convention used by all Win32 API functions and if you look at the export tables of DLLs like `KERNEL32.DLL` and `USER32.DLL` you'd see that all symbols are named like this.

The `_...@length` decoration gives the number of bytes occupied by the routine arguments. This is necessary since in the `stdcall` calling conventions it is the callee who cleans up the arguments from the stack and not the caller as is the case with the C calling convention. When the compiler generates a call to `func` with two 4-byte arguments, it puts a reference to `_func@8` in the object code. If the real `func` happens to have different number or size of arguments, its decorated name would be something different, e.g. `_func@12` and hence a link error would occur. This is very useful with dynamic libraries (DLLs). Imagine that a DLL was replaced with another version where `func` takes one additional argument. If it wasn't for the name mangling (the technical term for prepending `_` and adding `@length` to the symbol name), the program would still call into `func` with the wrong arguments and then `func` would increment the stack pointer with more bytes than was the size of the passed argument list, thus breaking the caller. With name mangling in place the loader would not launch the executable at all since it would not be able to resolve the reference to `_func@8`.

In your case it looks like the external library is not really intended to be used with this compiler or you are missing some pragma or compiler option. The `getarg` intrinsic takes two arguments - one integer and one assumed-sized character array (string). Some compilers pass the character array size as an additional argument. With 32-bit code this would result in 2 pointers and 1 integer being passed, totalling in 12 bytes of arguments, hence the `_getarg@12`. The `_getarg@16` could be, for example, 64-bit routine with strings being passed by some kind of descriptor.

As IanH reminded me in his comment, another reason for this naming discrepancy could be that you are calling `getarg` with fewer arguments than expected. Fortran has this peculiar feature of "prototypeless" routine calls - Fortran compilers can generate calls to routines without actually knowing their signature, unlike in C/C++ where an explicit signature has to be supplied in the form of a function prototype. This is possible since in Fortran all arguments are passed by reference and pointers are always the same size, no matter the actual type they point to. In this particular case the `stdcall` name mangling plays the role of a very crude argument checking mechanism. If it wasn't for the mangling (e.g. on Linux with GNU Fortran where such decorations are not employed or if the default calling convention was `cdecl`) one could call a routine with different number of arguments than expected and the linker would happily link the object code into an executable that would then most likely crash at run time.

Comment: The variant of getarg associated with the DVF/CVF/ifort lineage takes three visible arguments (argument number (integer), buffer for argument value (character), error code (integer)) and one hidden (buffer length)) - hence the @16.

Comment: @IanH, that would mean that the OP hasn't supplied the right number of arguments to `getarg`. Makes perfect sense to me.

Comment: C has implicit function declarations as well.

Answer (score 2):

This is totally implementation dependent. You did not say, which compiler do you use. The (nonstandard) intrinsic can exist in more versions for different integer or character kinds. There can also be more versions of the runtime libraries for more computer architectures (e.g. 32 bit and 64 bit).